# Passing data to factory method in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to build links in factory. I need to reach the url variable from template like data-url attribute. The problem is that I don't know how to reach it when I am in factory. Maybe there is some way of using directives to get the data-url attribute ?

```
myApp.factory('Survey', function ($resource) {
    var url; //I need this value somehow from template
    return $resource(url, {surveyId: '@id'});
});
```

Or should I use some other method or approach for this?

Comment: I tried `$rootScope` however when I pass attribute from controller `$attrs` to `$rootScope`. It some how executes the factory function before the attributes are actually stored in the `$rootScope`.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
myApp.factory('Survey', function ($resource) {
    return {
        fetchStuff: function(url) {
            return $resource(url, {surveyId: '@id'});
        }
    };
});
```

If you do not want to create an extra function you could always use a `provider`.

Comment: I was thinking about this before I posted my question. Could you explain a little bit more about provider ? What is the benefit of choosing provider instead of factory ?

Comment: Providers can be configured during the `app.config` phase. If you like examples by code take a look at this: https://gist.github.com/Mithrandir0x/3639232